# Can we see Allah or not?

Tags: allah

Salam

I am very confused regarding the concept of grasping the vision of God in Islam. There are two contradictory verses in the Quran that gives me a cognitive disambiguance.

6:103
No vision can grasp Him, but His Grasp is over all vision. He is the Most Subtle and Courteous, Well-Acquainted with all things.

2:115
And to Allah belongs the east and the west. So wherever you [might] turn, there is the Face of Allah . Indeed, Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing.

I am confused. Can we see Allah or not? 6:103 says we cannot see him but 2:115 says God is everywhere as in He is the Universe itself?

Comment: There are certainly different of opinions if you can see God in the hereafter or not.

Answer (score 1):

It can be said that you see God in everything, feel him in everything. As your (human) eyes behold a beautiful sunset on a vast desert, that is Allah. When you hold a new-born baby in your arms and feel love towards it, and understanding of its vulnerability and your responsibility to protect and nurture it... that is Allah.

As the first verse says,

> No vision can grasp Him

Your eyes are human eyes, in a living body. You have not yet passed on to the next world. With those eyes, you cannot ever directly see Allah. Unless you are to be the next prophet, your eyes will not see God directly.

> but His Grasp is over all vision

That sunset? Was brought on by Allah. The new-born? Allah. Everything right in the world, is Allah's work. Everything wrong in it, also His. He gives us strife to teach and learn. Enemies to vanquish. Friends to favor. We see these things *because* it is Allah's will to show them to us.

This last bit ties in to your second verse.

> Allah is all-Encompassing and all-Knowing

Everything in this world, and the next, is by Allah's will.

The question you have not asked: *when will I get to see Allah, with mine own eyes?*

When you have passed on to the next world, if your faith was true, your intentions honorable, and your deeds giving and needful.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that the inhabitants of Jannah can see Allah.

"Which Eye can handle the light of Allah ? The one who has created beauty himself  ? ")